# Anonymous meeting in Skype for Businnes

Tags: skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper, ucwa

Help please solve the following problem. I can not
sign in anonymously into the meeting using the Skype Web SDK.

On the following site it doesn't work: https://ucwa.skype.com/websdk

In the official  [example](https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-web-sdk-samples/tree/master/SkypeWebSDKOnlineSample)  
everything works (signin, signout, chat, conference), except, of course, anonymous meeting.

I had a question: does this service at all, and if someone did it, answer, please.

Comment: Does this service what? Can you clarify what it is that you want to do and what you are having troubles with?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot pragmatically manipulate Skype without an authenticated user. Anonymous users may join your Skype meeting (if your configuration allows for it) but they do so using a publicly available Skype client (native or web).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the sample you are looking at is for **Skype for Business Online**. Its not meant to work with **onprem**. Its indeed not working anymore. 
You can make use of this repo: https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-docs/tree/master/Skype/Trusted-Application-API/samples/AnonMeetingJoinSamples and set up your own UCAP cloud application. Follow all the steps in the readMe and and on this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/trusted-application-api/docs/anonymousmeetingjoin

If you want further information for Skype for Business check out this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/ucwa2_0generalreference

If you have a specific question, feel free to ask